# Selecting different values for inner dimension of hierarchical index in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a big table with a hierarchical index, and am trying to select a subset of it. The real table in question has 3 levels to the axis-0 index, and I want all values on levels 1 and 2 and one choice of level 3.

For a small 2-level example of what I'm trying to do, here's the data frame setup:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'I1': [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3], 
                   'I2': ['foo', 'bar', 'blatz', 'blam',
                          'foo', 'bar', 'blatz', 'blam',
                          'foo', 'bar', 'blatz', 'blam'],
                   'V': np.arange(12)})
df = df.set_index(['I1', 'I2'])
print df
```

producing a data frame:

```
           V
I1 I2       
1  foo     0
   bar     1
   blatz   2
   blam    3
2  foo     4
   bar     5
   blatz   6
   blam    7
3  foo     8
   bar     9
   blatz  10
   blam   11
```

I then have a selector series:

```
> sel = pd.DataFrame({'I1': [1,2,3], 'I2': ['foo', 'blatz', 'bar']}).set_index(['I1'])
> print sel
       I2
I1       
1     foo
2   blatz
3     bar
```

So what I am trying to do is use `sel` to select a subset of `df`. If I just wanted the same I2 value for each I1, `xs` would do the trick, but it doesn't seem to work with a series rather than a single value.

I tried unstacking `df` and using the series to select columns, but that didn't seem to be right (and ran my machine out of memory).

My next attempt will be to reset the indexes on both `df` and `sel` and then use a join. Is that really the best way to do this, or is there a better trick that I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your intuition to use `join` is good. That's the Pandas-esque way of doing that:

```
sel = pd.DataFrame({'I1': [1,2,3], 'I2': ['foo', 'blatz', 'bar']}).set_index(['I1','I2'])
print df.join(sel, how = 'right')

          V
I1 I2      
1  foo    0
2  blatz  6
3  bar    9
```